# Stop google from saving my photos/images online

Tags: google-photos

Today I got one of those "A year ago today..." notifications from google where it showed a photo I took a year ago today and It was really weird because I considered that photo (and in general all the photos I take, as well as screenshots, etc) to be private and I don't want them stored in the f***ing cloud.

I've looked into the "Manage your google account" options but couldn'd find a way to shut this cloud backup or whatever is called down.

Can someone tell me how to keep the photos/images/screenshots/etc off the cluod and just keep them on my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid):

1. Open the Google Photos app;
2. Sign in to your account, if you aren't already signed in;
3. Tap your account profile photo or initial in the top right corner;
4. Select Photos settings;
5. Select Back up & sync.
6. Tap Back up & sync to turn off.